# Setup Guice bindings in Kotlin

Tags: guice, kotlin, extension-function

I want to setup Guice bindings so I created a module in Java that works perfectly:

```
public class CrashLoggerModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(CrashLogger.class).to(ConcreteCrashLogger.class);
    }
}
```

Then I converted this code to Kotlin:

```
public class CrashLoggerModule : AbstractModule() {
    override fun configure() {
        bind(javaClass<CrashLogger>()).to(javaClass<ConcreteCrashLogger>())
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the Kotlin version of this class doesn't work anymore. This happens because Kotlin calls its internal method `public fun <A, B> A.to(that: B): Pair<A, B>` instead of `LinkedBindingBuilder<T>.to(Class<? extends T> c)` which results in Guice binding not being set up correctly.

How can I specify explicitly that I want to use the class method and not the extension function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is:

```
bind(javaClass<CrashLogger>())!!.to(javaClass<ConcreteCrashLogger>())
```

you can also do an explicit cast to the type bind returns or run KAnnotator on Guice.

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't notice `bind()` returns a nullable reference.

Comment: But we still need to remove a.to(b) method from stdlib, it's clashing with so many things...

Comment: This isn't a problem anymore since the member function now takes precedence over an extension function.

Answer (score 4):

I had equal problem with this code, but in my case I can't import function kotlin.jvm.javaClass in Intellij IDEA 2016 no matter what I do. So I resolve problem in following way:

`bind(CrashLogger::class.java).to(ConcreteCrashLogger::class.java)`

//kotlin version = '1.0.6'